# Improve Performance of Generating List

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

I have a list that consists of 413 objects.  Now, I am creating a new list based off of those objects to export to Excel.

```
lstDailySummary = (List<DailySummary>)Session["Paging"];

List<ExportExcel> lstExportedExcel = lstDailySummary
    .Select(x => new ExportExcel
    {
        PropertyOne = x.ACInfo.RegNumber,
        PropertyTwo = db.MyTable.Find(x.NavProperty.subcategoryID).Text,
        PropertyThree = x.NavProperty.text,
        PropertyFour = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Agcy.ToString())) ? x.codeAgcy.location : " ",
        PropertyFive = x.EventLocation,
        PropertySix = x.codeCounty.county,
        PropSeven = x.Flight,
        PropEight = x.FlightDay.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"),
        PropNine = x.IncidentNumber,
        PropTen = x.codeLocation.Location,
        PropEleven = x.Summary,
        PropTwelve = x.Total,
        PropThirteen = x.ATime
    })
    .ToList();
```

When in debug mode, using VS 2017, I am seeing this is taking between 47 and 52 seconds, so, right under a minute to execute.

Is there a faster method to use rather than `.Select` in this scenario?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with the code is more than likely in the 413 calls (one per item in the original list) to the database you are making here:

```
PropertyTwo = db.MyTable.Find(x.NavProperty.subcategoryID).Text
```

Instead of doing this, load all the values at once and consume them from memory:

```
var distinctSubcategoryIds = lstDailySummary
    .Select(x => x.NavProperty.subcategoryID)
    .Distinct();

var dataForPropertyTwo = db.MyTable
    .Where(x => distinctSubcategoryIds.Contains(x.Id))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Text);

List<ExportExcel> lstExportedExcel = lstDailySummary.Select(x => new ExportExcel
{
    PropertyOne = x.ACInfo.RegNumber,
    PropertyTwo = dataForPropertyTwo[x.NavProperty.subcategoryID],
    PropertyThree = x.NavProperty.text,
    PropertyFour = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Agcy.ToString())) ? x.codeAgcy.location : " ",
    PropertyFive = x.EventLocation,
    PropertySix = x.codeCounty.county,
    PropSeven = x.Flight,
    PropEight = x.FlightDay.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"),
    PropNine = x.IncidentNumber,
    PropTen = x.codeLocation.Location,
    PropEleven = x.Summary,
    PropTwelve = x.Total,
    PropThirteen = x.ATime
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Holy s***!! That dropped it to 3ms - 4ms.. I knew from the past that doing individual calls to the database decreases performance when dealing with lists.. but I didn't even think to use a dictionary or grab the distinct values.. thanks for your help!